# Uncaught ReferenceError: SP is not defined

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model, jquery

I am trying to implement to Sharepoint simple function from MSDN which I've placed in aspx file but I got this error in js web browser console: Uncaught ReferenceError: SP is not defined. Any ideas how to solve it?

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/MicrosoftAjax.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   function retrieveWebSite(siteUrl) {
       var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
       this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();

       clientContext.load(this.oWebsite);

       clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
           Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
           Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
       );
   }

   function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
       alert('Title: ' + this.oWebsite.get_title() +
           ' Description: ' + this.oWebsite.get_description());
   }

   function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
       alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
           '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
   }
   window.onload = retrieveWebSite;
</script>
<h1>Hello world</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

Call your function on,

For SharePoint 2010,

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(functionName, "sp.js");
```

For SharePoint 2013,

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', function () { 
// code goes here
 });
```

OR

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", functionName);
```

the problem is that the file sp.js, is not reffered and hence not getting loaded before the function call. That file contains the class whose object you have reffered. (ie - SP)

Comment: I've tried both youor examples for SP2013 but error still occures.

Comment: This does not give an answer. You can post your own question

Comment: Yeah you are right Asad Refai. Please post the question bud. Try debugging your code.

Comment: I am new to SP. Maybe I should give full reference to the sp.js file somehow?